What exact model of Orbea Alma did I buy?
I got this bike at a police auction. I guess it was stolen and the police could not find the original owner and they had an auction to resell the bike.
It’s an Orbea Alma and the labels/stickers have all been scratched off, so I can’t find any serial number.
It has 12 gears, an aluminum frame, and a Rockshox front fork.
I need some help to identify exactly what Orbea Alma model I got.
Any guesses??






What do you plan on doing with this information? Did you look at the different specs available on Orbea’s website?

If one of your photos had shown the right hand side of the bike and the components around the chain, I'm sure the question would be more easily answered.

@Noise From what I can see, they’ve got quite a mix of components. Shimano Deore-level 12s shifter, off-brand cranks (the preload cap isn’t Shimano’s pattern and the chainring interface isn’t the 12s type), a Chinese cassette, and some Shimano derailleur. Interesting

Tangential - given the source of the bike you should register the serial number with https://project529.com/ or whatever service your local police offer.   Don't assume this was done at the auction.  Perhaps even sticker it with your name and a phone number.  Nice bike !

Assuming original components you have an H20 or H30 Alma which they don’t make at the moment

You have an Aluminium frame
The brakes are BR200/201 models which are only used on that spec level.
Steel uppers on the forks.

Enjoy
